# Generating and storing Seed Phrase offline

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node, seed-phrase

I would like to be able to generate a new seed phrase using:

```
cardano-wallet recovery-phrase generate
```

...and use that for a new wallet, but do it offline. So the seed phrase is never onscreen on a network connected machine and only ever recorded on paper.

Is there a documented procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use BIP39 compatible library to generate 15/24 word mnemonics. If looking for CLI, you can use [cardano-addresses](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses), check out the Readme in the repo, the command to generate mnemonics would be:

```bash
cardano-address recovery-phrase generate --size 15 > phrase.prv

# exercise club noble adult miracle awkward problem olympic puppy private goddess piano fatal fashion vacuum
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **Yes**, you can generate and store your seed phrase offline.

When generating a **primary recovery phrase** for new Cardano CLI wallet, you can choose 15, 18, 21, or 24-word phrase. Optional additional protection can be provided with a **secondary recovery phrase** containing 9 or 12 words.

These two Medium stories will provide you with useful information how to do that:

[How does 12-word seed phrase work?](https://medium.com/geekculture/cryptocurrency-911-how-does-12-word-seed-phrase-work-9d892de9732)

[Cardano wallet Command Line Interface (Part one)](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-wallet-command-line-interface-part-one-ad0ee5ac8509)